# default param php function

Tags: php, function

I'd like to just modify the second default param in a function but I don't know how to

```
function test($a, $b = "b", $c = "c"){
    echo $a." ".$b." ".$c;
}

test("a");
test("a","z","e");
test("a","z");
```

I'd like for exemple to use this function keeping `$b` as default and changing `$c`.
I try

```
test("a",,"f");
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You just can't do that... you have to pass again the $b default value. The common use of default parameter is that the less set variable is set to the far right, for your example that mean $a will always be set, $b will be set sometimes and $c will be set rarely and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in PHP nowadays. You have to pass the default value manually like:

```
test("a", "b", "f"):
```

There exists a RFC about this: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/skipparams But it hasn't had any success yet.

Comment: It is possible ,We we can find default arguments of a function using ReflectionFunction

Comment: @shin This is not how I interpreted the question. I thought he wants to do it by a language feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ,

```
function test($a, $b = "b", $c = "c"){
    echo $a." ".$b." ".$c;
}

 function get_default_param($fn)
 {
 $function = new ReflectionFunction($fn);
 $default=array();

  foreach ($function->getParameters() as $param) {
  if ($param->isOptional()) {
    $default[]=$param->getDefaultValue() ;
}else{
 $default[]='';
}

}
return $default;
}


$default=get_default_param('test');//for getting all default parameters of 'test' as an array
test("a",$default[1],"f");
```

**Output**

```
 a b f
```

Comment: It is correct, yes, but doing it this way is too complicated to use it as an easy workaround I feel.

Comment: @bwoebi,Once we created get_default_param(),Then we can use easly.I dont know it is posible to do with an easy way

Comment: And that's also my opinion: there's no easy way. And this way costs a lot performance (though I cannot think of a better way)